# Get text selection for non-http pages in browserAction

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome extension, which is clips current text selection in the browser. When I use `chrome.contextMenus`, I can get the text selection even for local and Chrome internal pages such as about:version, because it has a convenient `OnClickData.selectionText` property.

Using content script is out of question, because it can't be injected in local/internal pages.

How can I get the current text selection for local web pages and internal pages, if I use browserAction? Probably it's not possible currently, but I can be missing some workaround?

Comment: context menus does help you get current text for all pages and yes content scripts can not be in injected it default pages!

Comment: I am aware of that, but if the user uses the browserAction instead of a contextMenu, then I can't access contextMenu helper info..

Comment: What do you exactly mean by local and internal pages?.

Comment: @riot_starter: You can refer my answer as an indirect way to handle 3 internal pages.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome-extension://` is a custom protocol of chrome and it restricts its usage.

However, If you have

- `chrome://newtab`
- `chrome://bookmarks`
- `chrome://history`
  in your list of internal pages you can get text selection by using override page(s). Override these with your own pages(Or Make them Look Similar) and get all events(s) or text selection from these pages.

**Ex:**

```
"chrome_url_overrides":{
    "newtab":"mypage.html"
}
```

Where `mypage.html` is your custom page.

Apart from `newtab` , `bookmarks` and `history` pages till date there is no method to get text selection through direct or indirect methods.

You can use `content scripts` for all standalone html pages, to get text selection!

## References

- [Override pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html)

#### P.S: There are individual API(s) for all the internal pages if you wish to get data but not DOM Events.

Comment: Is there a way to get selection for local web pages? It seems that content scripts do not work for pages loaded locally (file:///...)?